# Is it confirmed anywhere which of the Raith sisters appears in Wild Card?

Tags: the-dresden-files

Other than Lara Raith that is.

A total of three other Raith sisters appear in the Dresden Files Wild Card comics, none actually referred to by-name in comic and them all being seen together here.

[image]

And only here.

After the training session, one at least (at the back by the tree-filled window, hair down) isn't seen again in the story - seemingly being kept out of things as her sisters and brother handled the business that was going on.

I don't have any exact guesses on who she may be, other than perhaps one of the younger members of the household.

I do have *guesses* about two at least, specifically them being -

Natalia Raith

> Natalia Raith is described by Harry Dresden as taller and more masculine than her sister Elisa Raith. She wore a man's shirt with only one button closed. Her hair was long and messy from having just gotten up out of bed with the Naagloshii attack. She carried an exotic looking axe with the edge having an unusual concave shape.

and Elisa Raith

> Elisa is described by Harry Dresden as wearing nothing but weapons and silver body piercings on one eyebrow, one nostril, her lower lip and her nipples. She had dark, close-cropped hair except for the dark bangs that fell to cover one of her eyes. She carried a pair of wavy swords like Lara's.

As the above descriptions seem to go with the appearances of the sisters in Wild Card:

[image]

[image]

Although, on their wiki pages, neither of them are noted to have appeared in the comic, which is  in-canon in at least "broad strokes" - Jim writing the outlines of DF comics and also referencing them sometimes in books - so you would have thought, if this *were* them, it would be noted.

Casting doubt.

Hence, what I'm wanting to know is:

**While no names are given in comic, is there anywhere that *does* canonically confirm/specify who these sisters appearing in "Wild Card" are, that I have simply missed? As opposed to just assuming/making guesses?**

If there isn't, I'll just go with my former guesses - but if there is I would prefer to know for certain.

Comment: I'd guess that's Madeline. [The chronology allows it](https://www.reddit.com/r/dresdenfiles/comments/7xt2d9/all_the_stories_in_chronological_dresdenverse/), and she was closely involved with that branch of the family despite being a cousin rather than a sister.